# i want to attach a click evet for the selected items and show tooltip on mouse over in autocomplete control in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
  $(document).ready(function(){                
       $("#select3").fcbkcomplete({
            json_url: "data.txt",
            addontab: true,                   
            maxitems: 10,
            input_min_size: 0,
            height: 10,
            cache: true,
            newel: true,
            select_all_text: "select",
       });
   });
```

i am generating this above code in code behind.
i want to attach a click evet for the selected items and show tooltip on mouse over in autocomplete control in jquery

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the auto complete plugin renders the hint items in the "div" control. You could try something like

```
$("#select3 div").click(function() { });
$("#select3 div").title("...");
```

Hope this could be of some help!!

Answer (score 0):

According to http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete, this should work:

```
   $("#select3").fcbkcomplete({
        json_url: "data.txt",
        addontab: true,                   
        maxitems: 10,
        input_min_size: 0,
        height: 10,
        cache: true,
        newel: true,
        select_all_text: "select",
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            //your mouse over event, also includes keyboard arrow key
            //ui.item has the focused item data: ui.item.label or ui.item.value
            your show tooltip function here.
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            //your click event, also includes enter key and tab key to select
            //event.target is your item
            your click action here.
        }
   });
```

Hope this helps.